# Как отправить POST запрос в jQuery Ajax в CP1251?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, cp1251, post

Есть форум IPB 2.3.6 с кодировкой cp1251. Надо запостить сообщение в тему.

Вот код:

```
(function NewPost(fid, tid, auth_key) {
    var ajaxUrl = 'http://example.com/index.php?';    
    var text = "Тестовый пост";    
    var baseData = { act: "Post", CODE: "03", f: fid, t: tid, auth_key: auth_key, Post: text};    
    var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({             
        type: "POST",    
        data: baseData,    
        dataType: "html",    
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1251',
        url: ajaxUrl    
        })
        jqxhr.done( function(data) {    
        console.log('Новое сообщение создано')   
      })
    jqxhr.fail( function(err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
}) (227, 11764579, '17cc48183ae68447d8836f40932ba4e4')
```

В результате на сайте выводится текст на UTF -> каракули.

Как решить проблему без изменений на сервере - форум не мой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. AJAX-запросы передаются только в UTF-8

Comment: Собственно и добавить то нечего :)

Comment: Т.е. если на стороне сервера делать iconv, то могло бы и получиться?

Comment: Да..  Так получится..

Comment: а AJAX с FormData?

Answer (score 3):

Я так решил, когда у меня проблема подобная возникла:

```
function sendForm(url, data, ok, error, callback) {
    var str = "";
    var boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary5zih7EsEnWJI1WJw';
    for(var i in data) {
        str += '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
        + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="'+i+'"\r\n\r\n'
        + data[i] + '\r\n';
    }

    var converted_str = UnicodeToWin1251(str);

    var send_arr = new Uint8Array(converted_str.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < converted_str.length; ++i) send_arr[i] = converted_str.charCodeAt(i);

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            if(this.status == 200) {
                ok(this.responseText);
            } else {
                error(this.responseText);
            }
            callback();
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
    xhttp.send(send_arr);
}

var DMap = {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9, 10: 10, 11: 11, 12: 12, 13: 13, 14: 14, 15: 15, 16: 16, 17: 17, 18: 18, 19: 19, 20: 20, 21: 21, 22: 22, 23: 23, 24: 24, 25: 25, 26: 26, 27: 27, 28: 28, 29: 29, 30: 30, 31: 31, 32: 32, 33: 33, 34: 34, 35: 35, 36: 36, 37: 37, 38: 38, 39: 39, 40: 40, 41: 41, 42: 42, 43: 43, 44: 44, 45: 45, 46: 46, 47: 47, 48: 48, 49: 49, 50: 50, 51: 51, 52: 52, 53: 53, 54: 54, 55: 55, 56: 56, 57: 57, 58: 58, 59: 59, 60: 60, 61: 61, 62: 62, 63: 63, 64: 64, 65: 65, 66: 66, 67: 67, 68: 68, 69: 69, 70: 70, 71: 71, 72: 72, 73: 73, 74: 74, 75: 75, 76: 76, 77: 77, 78: 78, 79: 79, 80: 80, 81: 81, 82: 82, 83: 83, 84: 84, 85: 85, 86: 86, 87: 87, 88: 88, 89: 89, 90: 90, 91: 91, 92: 92, 93: 93, 94: 94, 95: 95, 96: 96, 97: 97, 98: 98, 99: 99, 100: 100, 101: 101, 102: 102, 103: 103, 104: 104, 105: 105, 106: 106, 107: 107, 108: 108, 109: 109, 110: 110, 111: 111, 112: 112, 113: 113, 114: 114, 115: 115, 116: 116, 117: 117, 118: 118, 119: 119, 120: 120, 121: 121, 122: 122, 123: 123, 124: 124, 125: 125, 126: 126, 127: 127, 1027: 129, 8225: 135, 1046: 198, 8222: 132, 1047: 199, 1168: 165, 1048: 200, 1113: 154, 1049: 201, 1045: 197, 1050: 202, 1028: 170, 160: 160, 1040: 192, 1051: 203, 164: 164, 166: 166, 167: 167, 169: 169, 171: 171, 172: 172, 173: 173, 174: 174, 1053: 205, 176: 176, 177: 177, 1114: 156, 181: 181, 182: 182, 183: 183, 8221: 148, 187: 187, 1029: 189, 1056: 208, 1057: 209, 1058: 210, 8364: 136, 1112: 188, 1115: 158, 1059: 211, 1060: 212, 1030: 178, 1061: 213, 1062: 214, 1063: 215, 1116: 157, 1064: 216, 1065: 217, 1031: 175, 1066: 218, 1067: 219, 1068: 220, 1069: 221, 1070: 222, 1032: 163, 8226: 149, 1071: 223, 1072: 224, 8482: 153, 1073: 225, 8240: 137, 1118: 162, 1074: 226, 1110: 179, 8230: 133, 1075: 227, 1033: 138, 1076: 228, 1077: 229, 8211: 150, 1078: 230, 1119: 159, 1079: 231, 1042: 194, 1080: 232, 1034: 140, 1025: 168, 1081: 233, 1082: 234, 8212: 151, 1083: 235, 1169: 180, 1084: 236, 1052: 204, 1085: 237, 1035: 142, 1086: 238, 1087: 239, 1088: 240, 1089: 241, 1090: 242, 1036: 141, 1041: 193, 1091: 243, 1092: 244, 8224: 134, 1093: 245, 8470: 185, 1094: 246, 1054: 206, 1095: 247, 1096: 248, 8249: 139, 1097: 249, 1098: 250, 1044: 196, 1099: 251, 1111: 191, 1055: 207, 1100: 252, 1038: 161, 8220: 147, 1101: 253, 8250: 155, 1102: 254, 8216: 145, 1103: 255, 1043: 195, 1105: 184, 1039: 143, 1026: 128, 1106: 144, 8218: 130, 1107: 131, 8217: 146, 1108: 186, 1109: 190}

function UnicodeToWin1251(s) {
    var L = []
    for (var i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        var ord = s.charCodeAt(i)
        if (!(ord in DMap)) {
            L.push(63);
        } else {
            L.push(String.fromCharCode(DMap[ord]))
        }
    }
    return L.join('')
}
```

Использование:

`sendForm("test.php", {name:"имя", message:"Сообщение"}, function(){alert("отправлена");}, function(){alert("не отправлена");}, function(){});`

Работает так: формируем multipart/form-data, потом конвертируем в cp1251 и в виде бинарного массива отдаем в запрос.

Кроссбраузерность не проверял, в ТЗ к счастью только Chrome.

Comment: как быть с файлами?

Comment: Ну если у вас файл в UTF-8, а вам его надо отправить на сервер который вы не контролируете в cp1251, то прочитайте его в строку и вперёд. При отправке Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg", читать файл через input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange и FileReader

Answer (score 2):

Ну, вообще-то передать через AJAX cp1251 можно. Просто он не будет об этом знать. Если настроить принимающую сторону на прием cp1251 - все нормально будет. Способ я подробно описал где-то там:
http://qweewqrty.blogspot.ru/2013/10/win1251-ajax.html
Естественно, там нет глупых перекодировок в utf и обратно. И да, принимать по аяксу можно что угодно, не только utf. Просто укажите правильный Content-type.

Answer (score 1):

Может использовать xml для передачи данных?

Comment: А толку?  Еще раз повторю: ВСЕ AJAX-запросы передаются (и принимаются) только в кодировке UTF-8.